# Add Page in NextJS Project

Tags: next.js

hope all of you have a great day!

I want to ask something, i create new project using `npx create-next-app@latest` using typescript and tailwind as css, look like this:

[image]

then i got the stack folder tree like this:

[image]

Then the problem is, i got confused, previous project using nextJS the file tree is not like this, now i didn't have folder called `Pages` anymore, is this the new thing?

Then i realized that i can't create new page (ex: i want to create `test page`, previously i just create folder named `test` inside `pages` folder and create `index.tsx` file)

How can i create new page with this scheme?

Comment: Yes, new in v13. See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#the-app-router

Comment: Thanks for your comment, just realized, now when we want to add new page, is not `index.tsx` anymore, it change to `page.tsx` (inside the new folder)

Answer (score 0):

Inside app you can create folder else file name.
folder name will work as part of url and file name words as end part or url.

```
structure : App>testcomponent>component1>index.js
url : ../testcomponent/component1/index.js
```

there could be multiple level of nesting in folder names to create nested routes.

For dynamic routes

```
structure : App>testcomponent>component1>[id].js
url : ../testcomponent/component1/index.js
```

you need to pass the id number at the end of URL to open that particular file as per requirement.

Same applies to folder.

Here id is just and example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i already create some folder `test` as your mention, and add some file `index.tsx` in the folder, but when i access it with the `url/test`, i got 404

Comment: Holly molly, now when we want to add new page, is not `index.tsx` anymore, it change to `page.tsx`